# Is it possible to Cast an Object to a not related Class?

Tags: c++, object, inheritance, pointers, casting

Say I have two classes with different names but the exactly same structure. It there a way to cast an object of the one class to one of the other?

This might sound stupid to do but there is a reason why I want to do that. The architecture of my application provides the abstract classes `component` and `storage` The ready application will contain several specialized components derived from `component` and each of them will define its own storage type, derived from `storage`. During initialization of the application, for each component there will be a storage object of its custom storage type created and passed as pointer to the component.

This way all component stay completely independent which is great for re-usability and testing. But, of course, there is a need to exchange informations between components. To do that with independence in mind, I want to let two components get a storage pointer pointing to the same storage. The pointer by constraint must be of the component specific storage type.

framework code (abstract classes)

```
class Storage {};

class Component {
public:
    void SetStorage(Storage* storage);
private:
    Storage* storage;
};
```

example component

```
class PhysicsStorage : public Storage;
class PhysicsComponent : public Component;
```

another component

```
class CollisionStorage : public Storage; // same structure as PhysicsStorage as both components need the same data like world coordinates and rotations of all forms in the 3d space
class CollisionComponent : public Component;
```

main application

```
#include "system.h"

PhysicsStorage Worlddata;

PhysicsComponent Physics;
CollisionComponent Collision;

Physics.SetStorage(&Worlddata);
Collision.SetStorage(&Worlddata); // this points to a PhysicsStorage but that is actually the same like a CollisionStorage which is expected
```

So I wonder if there is a way of casting the pointer of say `PhysicsStorage*` to `CollisionStorage*`. In this case, both are defined in the file of their related component class. And both are derived from abstract `Storage`.

I only want to do that in the case that both custom storage types have exactly the same structure. Otherwise it would be senseless. I am not so familiar with advances pointer usage so I wonder if there is a way to do that. What I know is that you can cast to a base class, but this isn't what I want here. Using a shared storage type for two components would break independence. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You want to keep them independent, but to have the same structure? Something doesn't sound right here. Pick one and your problem will solve itself.

Comment: This sounds fairly complicated, could you post some code (pseudo or otherwise) indicating what you want to try and achieve?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes. That way both components can be used separate from each other. So there is a kind of independence there. But you are right, two components sometimes must be, like I already said, contentual dependent.

Comment: Basically, I think this is a self-inflicted problem: you have two classes that need to share some data. So you define the structure of that data and *share* that definition. That's the simple solution. But you decided to discard that solution, creating a larger problem, to gain some benef- wait, what benefits?

Comment: Based on your recent edit, why can you not just pass them as the base class? Any shared methods/accessors can be defined there.

Comment: Maybe you need an AbstractComponentFactoryProxyManager. IOW: your design is overly complex.

Comment: @pstrjds. Would that give the component access to all the data of the derived storage type? Sorry, as I mentioned, I am not so familiar with pointers.

Comment: @WTP'--. Additionally, this isn't my final architecture. There is more like an event system and a `system` class putting all together for easy use. But I will also modify and improve the architecture the next weeks before I start developing the application. So there is still a change that it will become more easy! ;-)

Comment: @sharethis It would give the component access to all of the base class data, not any data that is specific to the derived class; but since you said they have the same structure this shouldn't be a problem for you. If they have the same structure then the have the same data members and functions. Put that in the base class and pass as pointers to the base class (see cdhowie's answer).

Comment: @sharethis The point is, you've said you want to be able to cast between two structures which have the same layout.. so they interchangeable, why again are they different?

Comment: @pstrjds. I can't put that in the base class since the structure of a storage is completely free and only specified by specific components. But only a few components will share data. So the base class must stay empty. But I figured out that something like `static_cast<Derived*>(BasePointer)` would work for me.

Comment: @Collin. For consistency of the architecture. I don't want to take care of each individual storage type. This way every component has it's own storage type and there are no shared storages by design. This also lets all components work independent of others. But on a higher level I want to assign the same data to some components to let all of them read and modify them.

Comment: I have huge suspicions that `static_cast` will not work for you or anyone. Unless your definition of "working" includes having undefined behaviour. (I suppose your abstract classes all have virtual destructors; if they don't, your program will probably not have undefined behaviour due to the static_cast, but due to the lack of virtual destructors)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes. So there is no way around a storage manager? That's too bad.

Comment: You've never given any reason for storage to exist. Why not just.. store things in the component class?

Comment: @DeadMG. Imagine the physics component needs the position and shape of forms in the world as well as the collision detection component and the render component. The components should stay independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work, and it may not.  I believe this is a case of undefined behavior, and I would avoid doing this in production code.

Consider instead pushing the common fields and methods up into a new class and having `ComponentOneStorage` and `ComponentTwoStorage` inherit that class.  Then you can pass around pointers/references to the base class instead, which will give you access to the common data without having to cast between incompatible pointer types.

Comment: Could I pass pointers to the base storage class and then `static_cast` them back to two different custom storage classes? Or this it just what you believe to be undefined.

Comment: In addition to @cdhowie 's concerns, I'd also point out that using two unrelated classes and keeping them identical is a maintenance nightmare in the waiting. Any change to one file MUST be made to the other. That's the kind of thing you try to avoid.

Comment: @sharethis Casting a pointer of one type to a pointer of another, incompatible type results in undefined behavior.  Even if the binary layout is the same, the types are semantically incompatible since one is not a direct descendant of the other.  In other words, if you access an object through a pointer whose base type is not the type of the pointed-to object or that of a super-type, the resulting behavior is undefined.

Comment: @cdhowie. It is a subtype for sure, but another then the one the pointer was created for. So I will think of other ways of reaching my goal now.